# Exibir registros em ordem conforme a quantidade que tem em uma tabela

Tags: php, pdo

Eu tenho duas tabelas no banco de dados, uma fica salvo todos os grupos e na outra os membros dos grupos.
Eu quero fazer uma página de Grupos Populares, exibiria os grupos que possuem mais membros em ordem de quantidade. Por se tratar de duas tabelas eu não sei como poderia fazer isto. O que eu escrevi até agora:

```
<?php 
//Seleciona todos os grupos
$sql = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM groups');
while($row = $sql->fetch()){

//Conta a quantidade de membros que tem em cada grupo 
$sql_count = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM group_memberships WHERE group_id = ?', 
             [$row['id']]);
?>
```

Comment: Talvez você possa fazer diretamente no SQL com `SELECT group_id, count(*) FROM group_memberships GROUP BY group_id ORDER BY 2 DESC;`.

Comment: Mas ai no caso está selecionando somente os membros. Não entendi muito bem o que faz exatamente essa query.

Comment: Agora eu entendi, obrigado amigos <3